Conditional html heading tag based on variable in knockout.js
Is it possible to set the html element in knockout.js programmatically?
For example, the user can choose the heading level (from h1 - h6 and p if it's no heading).
And in frontend I then have a variable data.headingLevel which contains the html tag.
Currently I'm doing it like this, which is working. But I absolutely hate it to do it like that.
<h1 if="data.headingLevel == 'h1'" html="data.text"></h1>
<h2 if="data.headingLevel == 'h2'" html="data.text"></h2>
<h3 if="data.headingLevel == 'h3'" html="data.text"></h3>
<h4 if="data.headingLevel == 'h4'" html="data.text"></h4>
<h5 if="data.headingLevel == 'h5'" html="data.text"></h5>
<h6 if="data.headingLevel == 'h6'" html="data.text"></h6>
<p if="data.headingLevel == 'p'" html="data.text"></p>


Can we do this in one line by binding the element tag?
Something like this:
<p data-bind="element: data.headingLevel" html="data.text"></p>

In the line above I'd love for the <p> to simply switch to the variables element.I don't want to insert a new child element. (Like the component binding does)

If you are going to use dynamic html content like your example you could do
var element = "h1";
var data = "My h1 content"

ko.applyBindings({ bar: `<${element}>${data}</${element}>`})

https://jsfiddle.net/tLwq1rab/
If you you want your content to be databound knockout I would use tample binding. Were the template dictates what element is rendered
